# Host ServiceStack in HyperFastCGI, error fcgi-transport.c:444: parse_params(): Can't find app! HOST

Tags: nginx, servicestack, centos7

I need to install the web service on Linux, but ran into such a problem, can you tell me how can it be solved?

Thanks!

OC: CentOS7

Mono JIT compiler version 4.8.0 (Stable 4.8.0.520/8f6d0f6 Wed Mar 15 10:51:49

```
#: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib hyperfastcgi4 /config=/etc/hyperfastcgi/hfc.config /loglevels=All

[2017-04-07 17:33:09Z] Debug HyperFastCgi
libev.c:475: Listen(): libevent version: 2.0.21-stable
libev.c:489: Listen(): libevent is using epoll for events.
fcgi-transport.c:444: parse_params(): Can't find app! HOST='109.120.151.151' port=443 path='/index.aspx'
fcgi-transport.c:444: parse_params(): Can't find app! HOST='109.120.151.151' port=443 path='/favicon.ico'
```

Nginx:

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
     server 127.0.0.1:9000;    
     keepalive 80;
 }

   server {
         listen   80;
         server_name  109.120.151.151;
         return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
 }

 server {
          listen   443 ssl;
          server_name  109.120.151.151;

          ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/xxxx.crt;
          ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/xxx.key;

          proxy_connect_timeout 600;
          proxy_read_timeout 600;
          proxy_send_timeout 600;
          send_timeout       600;

          location ~ /\.  { deny all; }

          location / {
                  root /var/www/wsteleport/;
                  index index.html index.htm default.aspx Default.aspx;
                  fastcgi_index index.aspx;
                     fastcgi_keep_conn on;
                  fastcgi_pass fastcgi_backend;
                  include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

                  fastcgi_split_path_info ^((?U).+\.as.x)(/?.+)$;
                     fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
          }  
 }



  HyperFastCGI:

<configuration>
    <server type="HyperFastCgi.ApplicationServers.SimpleApplicationServer">
        <host-factory>HyperFastCgi.HostFactories.SystemWebHostFactory</host-factory>
        <threads min-worker="80" max-worker="0" min-io="4" max-io="0" />
    </server>

<listener type="HyperFastCgi.Listeners.NativeListener">
    <apphost-transport type="HyperFastCgi.Transports.NativeTransport">
        <multithreading>ThreadPool</multithreading>
    </apphost-transport>
        <protocol>InterNetwork</protocol>
        <address>127.0.0.1</address>
        <port>9000</port>
    </listener>

    <apphost type="HyperFastCgi.AppHosts.AspNet.AspNetApplicationHost">
        <log level="Debug" write-to-console="true" />
        <add-trailing-slash>false</add-trailing-slash>
    </apphost>
    <web-applications>
        <web-application>
            <name>109.120.151.151</name>
            <vhost>109.120.151.151</vhost>
            <vport>80</vport>
            <vpath>/</vpath>
            <path>/var/www/wsteleport/</path>
        </web-application>
    </web-applications>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Mismatch between *port* and `vport` settings.

Comment: @RichardSmith this is a official sample: [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ServiceStackApps/mono-server-config/master/hfc-config/hfc.config)

Comment: But you are not using port 80 as the sample implies. You are using port 443 as indicated by the error message..

Comment: @RichardSmith I have to make vport 443?

Comment: @RichardSmith I changed vport 443 but not working